# Nodes not put at same distance from points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the code for a triangle. Points A and C are on a horizontal line. I used the options `label=225` to position the label "A" and `label=-45` to position the label "C."  They are at significantly different distances below the horizontal line, but I want them at the same distance. I used the commands `\coordinate[label=225:$A$] (A) at (0,0);` and `\node[label=-45:$C$] at (C){};`.  I guess placing one label with `\coordinate` and the other label with `\node` made the difference.

I tried using the command `\coordinate[label=-45:$C$] (C) at C;` but `TikZ` would not compile it.  I guess that what follows `at` must be a point specified in rectangular coordinates or polar coordinates.  I did not see anything in the manual saying this, though.  Is there a way to use the `\coordinate` command?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=225:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=90:$B$] (B) at (60:6);

%These commands position vertex C, label it C, and positions the label southeast of the vertex.
\path[overlay,name path=horizontal] (A) -- ++(10,0);
\path[overlay,name path=BC] (B) -- ($(B)!2!75:(A)$);
\path[name intersections={of= horizontal and BC, by=C}];
\node[label=-45:$C$] at (C){};

%This command draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\coordinate[label=-45:$C$] (C) at C;` did not compile most likely because it requires brackets like  `at (C)`.

Comment: @Alenanno  I tried `\coordinate[label=-45:$C$] (C) at (C);`. It was not compiled, too.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: The labels were aligned in my example, why don't you use the same method I used?

Comment: @Alenanno  I understand your code fine, and I am sure that with some practice, I can modify it to draw triangles with specified angles.  I am trying to get familiar with the code that percusse provided.

Comment: Modify it? It already draws specified angles as is. But I understand why you asked this question now.

Comment: @Alenanno  If I need to draw a triangle with different angles, I can easily modify your code to have `TikZ` draw it.

Comment: Ah in that sense, got it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `A` and `B`, you're labeling coordinates.  For `C` you're labeling a node.  Coordinates are essentially zero dimensional nodes without content.  Nodes have associated `inner sep` and `outer sep`.  Set those to zero each and you should get the desired result.

```
\node[label=-45:$C$,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (C){};
```

You can compare the difference between using nodes and coordinates as in

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=225:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=90:$B$] (B) at (60:6);

%These commands position vertex C, label it C, and positions the label southeast of the vertex.
\path[overlay,name path=horizontal] (A) -- ++(10,0);
\path[overlay,name path=BC] (B) -- ($(B)!2!75:(A)$);
\path[name intersections={of= horizontal and BC, by=C}];
\node[label={[red]-45:$C$}] at (C){};
\coordinate[label={[blue]-45:$C$}] (tmp) at (C);

%This command draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**A few comments about naming conventions for nodes and coordinates**

While the following code works fine in the 3.0 version of TikZ, I don't recommend it.

```
\coordinate[<various options>] (C) at (C);
```

To begin with, it's circular, and I can't see much benefit to this particular circularity.  But, more importantly, it makes your code harder to read and understand.  And, when you start building on to old code; when you want move some snippet of code that you really liked to a new environment;... etc., such a coding approach seems rife for potential bugs or unintended side effects, and could potentially be very hard to debug.
So, unless you have very clear reasons to do so, I would avoid this type of circular referencing and naming.

Making a rather broad generalization here, the difference between a `node` and `coordinate` is that a `node` is used to place objects (whether text or graphics etc.) at a certain location, and a `coordinate` is used to name a particular location that you'll want to reference again later.  The `node` syntax allows you to combine both of these functions---a `coordinate` is just simply a very special kind of node (one that doesn't require *content*).

So, if you're going to use `\coordinate`, then you should have in mind the need to name the location.  If you don't need to name the location, `\node` just seems a better choice.  However, you may feel `\coordinate` is easier since you do not have to worry about *content* or any of the `inner sep` and `outer sep` business.  But, if the coordinate isn't something that is going to be referenced again, then name it in manner that makes this intention clear:  hence in the above code I name the coordinate `tmp`.  When I reread my code later, this immediately tells me, "this is a coordinate that I never again refer to."  .... which tells me a lot:  in particular, it means that changing that coordinate to a proper `node` will not break my code later on!  If I later decide I am going to later reference this coordinate, then it will be important that I change its name from the *throw-away* name `tmp` to something else.

Names of coordinates and nodes should be meaningful, particularly when building complex diagrams.  So, I would never just name a coordinate (or node) `<anything>`.  I will pick a name that will help me understand the purpose being served.  Names don't have to be long.  They can be quite compact.  For example, a node in the upper left hand corner of some diagram might be named `N/ULC` but then in my code I'll also write

```
%% N=node
%% U=upper
%% L=left
%% C=corner
```

so that in a year or two later, I'll understand what the obscure name `N/ULC` was supposed to mean.  Also, when it comes to refactoring code, I've found that a smart naming convention is better than the lazy and quick naming convention of

```
 \node (<single letter name>) at (.....) {....};
```

Comment: Nice illustration!  What is `tmp`?  Why don't the commands `\coordinate[label=-45:$C$] (C) at (C);` or `\coordinate[label=-45:$C$] (C) at C;` get compiled?

Comment: @Adelyn I can't say why `\coordinate[label....] (C) at (C);` doesn't compile. It works for me.  Perhaps you need to update TikZ to 3.0.  Regarding `\coordiante[...] (C) at C;` the syntax is just wrong.  You need the parentheses around the location of the node for the parser to find it.

Comment: @Adelyn Personally, the circularity of `\coordinate (C) at (C)` bothers me.  And whether it's allowed or not, I don't think it would be a good practice to follow.  Since nodes don't require names, I would go with the solution of `\node[label....,inner sep=0pt] at (C) {};`  I believe, it says better what you're doing and makes the code more readable.

Comment: OK.  I'm glad that you told me that `\coordinate (C) at (C);` compiles for you.  I now know to look at the version of `TikZ` that I have.  Ummm ... how do I find what version of `TikZ` that I have?

Comment: @Adelyn Open the documentation.  From the command line `texdoc tikz`.  The first page of the documentation will tell you which version you have.  Alternatively  in the `log` file there should be a line which reads something like `Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)` which tells you the version.

Comment: @Adelyn Version 3.0 comes with the most recent update of LaTeX (at least in TexLive).

Comment: By the way, if I am not labeling a point, I prefer not to use `\node[label....,inner sep=0pt] at (C) {};` because I don't like specifying `{}`.

Comment: What is `tmp`?  (I am guessing it is an abbreviation for "temporary.")

Comment: @Adelyn I use `tmp` as a throw-away name if I don't intend to use it again.

Comment: You don't like `\coordinate (C) at (C);`.  So, you use ` `\coordinate (anything) at (C);`. Is that right?

Comment: @Adelyn I've updated the answer to address some of your questions about naming conventions.  I hope the added material clarifies somethings.

Comment: That is a concise discussion of the uses of and distinction between `\node` and `\coordinate`.  I am sure it will be a benefit to many users of `TikZ`.

Comment: You may want to correct the spelling mistake in the first sentence.  You want to say "While the following code works `fine` in the 3.0 version of TikZ ... .".  I will delete this comment; so, there is no need to respond to it.